Is there a setting on ngx-charts-bar-horizontal to add horizontal lines between the bars?
We are wanting to add horizontal tick lines around the bars in our bar charts. I couldn't find a setting that did this automatically. I attempted every setting in the API doc. Is there a way to draw borders around each bar? Does anyone know of a way to make this happen?
Check out this image to see what I'm referring to.

